# Как правильно сделать метрику запросов к базе?

Tags: java, concurrency, mysql

Мини-проект на Java. Суть мини-проекта: Данные вводятся пользователем, кэшируются, кладутся в базу. Разумеется, тут есть многопоточность, т.е. будет тестовый клиент, запускающий кучу потоков на чтение/запись.

Как, собственно, правильно считать число запросов к базе?

Обязательно ли использование java.concurrency?

P.S.: Я тут прикинул следующий код, скажите насколько он тут уместен?

```
public class DAO {

public volatile int counter;

public void synchronized addNumber {

   try{
     ... // положили какое-то значение в базу
   } catch (Exception e) {
     // логируем
   } finally {
     counter++;
   }

}

// Аналогично будет и со взятием значения из базы

}
```

Comment: ++ - не является атомарной операцией. По сути здесь 3 операции: чтение, инкремент, запись. Поэтому volatile вас не спасет, т.к. возможно перекрытие последовательности операций в разных потоках. Что касается вопроса "как правильно", то нужо для начала четко понять, какие метрики вы собираете. Кол-во запросов к БД явно недостаточно и сама по себе одна такая метрика не имеет практического смысла.

Comment: "возможно перекрытие последовательности операций в разных потоках"

а почему произойдет перекрытие последовательности операций, если в синхронизированном методе одновременно не могут находиться два разных потока?


"Кол-во запросов к БД явно недостаточно и сама по себе одна такая метрика не имеет практического смысла."

понятно, что бессмысленно просто считать запросы, я просто потом число запросов буду делить на время работы программы и увижу число транзакций в секунду. 

потом можно будет, скажем поменяв схему кэширования, увидеть разницу между разными способами блокировок методов и пр.

Comment: @drcosmo, IMHO по поводу `synchronized` Вы правы. 

Вообще, при таком подходе к подсчету `counter++` можно разместь и прямо перед `try`, а блок `finally` просто выбросить.

Количество буковок уменьшится, код станет еще проще.

Comment: с таким же успехом можно использовать уже готовое решение:

http://metrics.codahale.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может проще взять [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) и не ломать голову?